# make contract able to receive funds

Tags: solidity

i added this code to my contract

```
    
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner{
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    
    receive() external payable {msg.value}
     
    fallback() external payable {msg.value}
```

also i tried this way

```
  constructor() public payable {
    
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner{
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    
    receive() external payable {msg.value}
     
    fallback() external payable {msg.value}
    
        
    }
```

and tried to use

```
contract AAA  is Ownable payable {
...

}
```

instead of

```
contract AAA  is Ownable {
...

}
```

the problem is that i cannot send ether to the contract even from the contract owner wallet address. what i do wrong?  `solidity ^0.6.12`

the error is `Error Message: execution reverted`

to send ether i use metamask and rinkeby testnet

Comment: The first one works (you can remove fallback and msg.value in receive). How are you sending ethers to the contract?

Comment: i use metamask to send

Comment: Do you have the failed rinkeby transaction hash?

Comment: your comment made me more confident so i decided to clean cache in chrome and restarted remix and it fixed the problem. thank you!